# jQuery Mobile - Any way to not cache a page?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a page that is dynamically updated after an AJAX call. It seems that jQuery Mobile loads the cache during the initial load of the page. If I revisit the page it always displays the initial version and not the updated page.

Is there anyway to force a page to refresh the cache or to simple perform a new request every time?

I have already tried adding `data-ajax="false"` to the anchor, which works but disables the transition animation so I'm still looking for other options.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you add a parameter to your AJAX URL that will change each time? Something like:

```
&nocache="+new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: That worked! Not sure why I didn't try it. And just to clarify, I'm using jQuery Mobile which automatically turns your standard anchors into AJAX calls and injects the results into the DOM. I added a random string to the end of the anchor with php.

`<a href="<? echo base_url(); ?>item/<? echo $item->id; ?>?r=<? echo rand(); ?>">`

Comment: Update: This seems to have broken some other functionality. None of my dialog work on the dynamic page.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see why it would break anything since it's just a parameter that isn't really even being used for anything other than busting the cache. Are you getting any errors?